# Passing through credentials to PyODBC from Flask-LDAP

Tags: python, sql-server, flask, ldap, pyodbc

I'm building an internal application for a corporation, using Flask-LDAP for authentication. In this way the firm can manage permissions without having to worry about a separate admin interface.

The firm has a sophisticated DBA staff with many MSSQL servers, and DB permissions are heavily managed on a per user/group basis. As such, I'd like to respect those permissions and not write the application with a super account. Is it possible to pass the LDAP ticket through to PyODBC? For many userland applications, we can simple set the connection on PyODBC to trusted, which makes things very clean. However I'm not sure how to do this for a web session.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I'm afraid I can't speak to Flask, but https://github.com/etianen/django-python3-ldap has a nice solution for Django with `LDAP_AUTH_SYNC_USER_RELATIONS`; I'm guessing you're looking for something similar with Flask?

Comment: Thanks @FlipperPa, I'm not sure that's what I'm looking for; I need to look at some documentation. We're a little flexible with web framework: only one web app of many planned as been completed. I wouldn't be against Django if it could handle what we're trying to do. Essentially we're looking to have a web portal that uses LDAP/SSO to grab and respect AD permissions. For DB enabled apps, we'd like to pass through those credentials to the DB driver somehow.

Comment: Depending on the LDAP you use, the typical strategy is to bind to the LDAP server (admin account for Active Directory, direct bind for something like OUD), and then your code will use the proper search criteria to find the user.  For OUD I actually re-bind as user and then pass the pw looking for match.  On match I initiate the session.